# Direct copy of the C drive of an old XP machine. What can I do with it?

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine

I have dug up a historical machine and I basically have a straight copy of the C: drive.  That is *all* I have.  I would like to take this and create a virtual machine from it.  Is that possible?  There are several services that were on this PC such as MySql that I would like to run again.

Comment: Make a backup before you try anything.  You'll likely get a BSOD on boot, as the install won't have the right drivers for the new hardware. I've read that you may be able to repair the install, but don't remember where that source is. Finally, you'll likely have to activate Windows.

Answer (score 1):

1. Figure out exactly which service pack was installed on the XP you copied.
2. Create a new XP virtual machine, and upgrade it to match the same service pack level.
3. Shut down the XP VM.
4. Mount its virtual hard drive to your host, or to a separate VM (as a data drive).
5. Ensure you are viewing all hidden/system files.
6. Copy your copy of the XP machine overtop of it, ensuring it overwrites everything.  You may need to add permissions for you current user to all the folders (in the context of the OS you're doing the copy from).
7. Dismount the drive from the work OS.
8. Start the XP VM, and cross your fingers. :)
9. If it doesn't boot, try using the XP automatic repair tools from the disk.

Comment: Where there is a will there is a way...